# Does iPhone update deletes media content?

Tags: iphone, backup, software-update

In my previous question I had asked about backing up the content of the iPhone in order to un-jailbreak my iPhone.

I was told that simply synchronizing with iTunes should do the trick, and I did that. However I did not get a certain answer about the media.

When I had applied the jailbreak patch I recall it completely obliterating everything I had: contacts, logs, apps and even mp3s and such.

I fear that after applying the update to my iPhone all my music will be gone (it will still be on my computer, but transferring all those files *again* and setting up playlists is something that generally I wish to avoid)

So all in all, after applying the update to my iPhone, what happens to my music, playlists, photos, videos and voice memos?

Answer (score 1):

A normal update doesn't delete your content, but I don't think you can delete your jailbreak with an update. You can always try. If it fails, you'll have to restore. Then you'll lose your music and apps from the device. ;-)